# Google-Drive: How to set criteria on sub-fields in the query parameter?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

My application is based on a tree-structure with a known root-folder (say 'theFolder') .

I'm able to retrieve **all** folders whose name is <theFolder>:

```
gapi.client.request(
    {
    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {
        q : "title='"+theFolder+"' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        fields: "items(description,id,modifiedDate,parents/id,title)"
        },
    callback: theCallback
    });
```

But, as I want only the root folder (if any), I tried in vain to add some criteria:

- `and parents.isRoot`
- `and parents.isRoot=true`
- `and parents/isRoot=true`
- `and (isRoot in parents)`

I understand this is related to the [Getting a list of files by folder on Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11400669/1530236) and more generally to: "how to set criteria on sub-fields?"

Comment: What do you mean by root folder. Do you mean the rot folder (in which case it's usually called "My Drive") or do you mean folders with no parents? (only some shared folders are like that)

Comment: @Nivco: "My" root folder is the highest folder in the hierarchy of folders and files, created by an application - where files and folders are simply instanciations of other objects. With Google-Drive this means a file created with a special mimeType and without setting its `parents.id`. There is an interesting side-effect: its metadata `parent.isRoot` is set to true.

Comment: Ah OK, what you mean is that you want to fetch the folders that have the root folder as a parent :) I got confused because of shared folders that can be "real" root folders (a root has no parents) yours are childs of the root folder. I've updated the response below. Let me know if that works

Comment: This `'root' in parents` sounds great! Looks like `'folderID' in parents` as described in [Getting a list of files by folder on Drive SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11400669/1530236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check that the root folder is in the parents of the folders you are looking for. For this you can use the 'root' alias for that folder.

try this in your search query:

```
'root' in parents
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid these unnecessary loops and bandwidth loads. But for the moment I think it's better to check, for each returned `items`, whether its metadata `parent.isRoot` is set to true. This is just a workaround - for the moment...

Comment: Well it;s a good feature request. Not sure we keep an index on this criteria but if so, we could expose it. I'll file the feature request internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe something like "How to set criteria on sub-fields in the query parameter?" could be more successful...

Comment: Works fine! Unfortunately, I can't "vote up" (requires 15 reputation)