# Google Drive REST API. Root listing

Tags: google-drive-api

I need listing all files of 'My Drive', but only the files and folders which are immediately below, not all the ones in the Drive at once.

Thanks for your help,

Mario

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest to use [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) API method.
Set `q` parameter on:

```
'root' in parents and trashed = false
```

What it means you can find on the page: [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). You can test API methods on the [APIs Explorer Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) page.

Please, see also:

- [Getting a list of files by folder on Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400669/getting-a-list-of-files-by-folder-on-drive-sdk).

Comment: Thanks. I was composing a bad URL by an error in the URI constructor.