# How to get list of files by folder on Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to build a web UI for users to navigate his/her Google Drive and select one or more documents to be referenced later on in a website from a DB. I am currently building a web interface using .NET.
The problem I am facing is that I can not find a single function to get a list of files by folder Id.
I tried using:

*...www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/BB0CHANGEDIDF5waGdzbUQ5aWs/children*

…but that will only give the files reference ID of the files within the folder (the so called children resource item), which means I have to loop through those files and create a call for each one of them in order to get all the metadata I need for my UI.
Unfortunately..

*...www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files*

..will list ALL my files with no filtering options by folder.
I would like to know if there is an efficient way of extracting a folder& file list from a single call to the Drive server by for a specific folder.

I also tried this ([based on answer to the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400669/getting-a-list-of-files-by-folder-on-drive-sdk/24719894#24719894)):
I am using Fiddler to do direct calls to the api. When I use this to make the call `

*...www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='BB0CHANGEDIDF5waGdzbUQ5aWs'*

I get an error:

```json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {wrongID
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

Even using [google's test page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) does not do it.
It looks like the "files" endpoint does not accept any parameter.

There has to be a way to achieve this!

Thank you for your help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive

Comment: Yes, their API docs are horrible :(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should be able to simply use [files/list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) with a parent query;

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='BB0CHANGEDIDF5waGdzbUQ5aWs'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your URL request string sample. The problem was that I was missing the: +in+parents      Can you tell me where this "in parents" add is documented? I completely missed it.

Comment: @user3199365 It's documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters), just search the page for "parents".

Comment: q='root' in parents will get you the top level folder, in case you were wondering

Comment: any documentation to api v3 please ?

Comment: Closest thing to docs I could find is https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files, but it doesn't explain what `parents` really is...

Comment: you should replace this: ' and the space in php script. use this: $getFiles_options = "&q=%27$folder_id%27%20in%20parents";  AND just replace the folder_id with yours.

Answer (score 26):

If you're doing this on javascript with v3, try this on the request body:

```js
{
  q: `'${folderId}' in parents`
}
```

However, this could also list the files from this folder that were deleted and are in the bin.So, you can do it like this:

```js
{
  q: `'${folderId}' in parents and trashed = false`
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this one works with drive_v3!

Answer (score 19):

Here's how to get specific fields of files in a folder using v3 API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="folderId"+in+parents&fields=files(md5Checksum,+originalFilename)
//
```

Replace "folderId" with the folder ID.

You can use `&fields=files(*)` to get all of the file's fields.