# How to get list of files from google drive api v3?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to get list of files from google drive folder using google drive apis.

I have referred this
[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720075/how-to-get-list-of-files-by-folder-on-google-drive-api?rq=1)

Above is not working for v3 apis. I think they have removed that support in version 3.
I also referred this [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)
But it is not clear how it works.

I am using java sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at version 3 (v3):

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java

There is some example Java code (do search for "public class Quickstart").

**Looking at the main method - you get a Drive, and can then page "through" files using:**

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
         .execute();
```

**Here is the main method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = getDriveService();

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
         .execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chocksaway. It worked after adding setQ method.               FileList files = service.files().list()
        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name,parents)")
        .setQ("'folder_id' in parents").execute();

Comment: Which package do I need to import to access getDriveService? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with udpdated URI:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

You could try the online demo with OAuth at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list where you will find some more information on how to use the API and the OAuth.