# Is it possible to access Google Drive folders just by API key

Tags: google-api

Trying to get my head around the Google Drive API and being stuck on if I can get folders just via API key bypassing the OAuth2 authorization.

Particularly referring to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720075/how-to-get-list-of-files-by-folder-on-google-drive-api) , which states it is simply possible by doing:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='FOLDERID'+in+parents&key=APIKEY
```

I'm getting an authorisation issue although the API key is correct. Also I find the `' '` really weird so I tried without and it gives me a `404`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When the files in a folder are retrieved by drive.files.list using the API key, the folder is required to be shared. For example, as a test, how about sharing a sample folder and try it again? At that time, please do the urlencode to the endpoint like ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27FOLDERID%27+in+parents&key=APIKEY``. And then, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at API console. If this information was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know it is possible to make files public via Share -> advanced -> public. But I don't see this option for folders itself. It seems that folders by itself are just accessible via `folderId` automatically or can be shared via email? I might be missing something here.

Comment: Hey actually thanks, encoding worked!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your issue was solved, can you post it as an answer and accept it? I think that this will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whomever it may be helpful but the issue  is solved by URL encoding the `'`:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27FOLDER_ID%27+in+parents&key=KEY_ID
```

and it works just fine.