# Getting an id for existing dir on Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to get an id for an existing dir on Google Drive.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = drive.about().get().execute();
  com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Children.List list =
      drive.children().list(about.getRootFolderId());
  Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> itr = list.entrySet().iterator();
  Entry<String, Object> s;
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    s = itr.next();
    System.out.println(s.getKey() + "::" + s.getValue());
  }
```

Right now this code is giving an output -

```
folderId::0APcEBFk-CF2pUk9PVA
```

which is probably not the correct id because I have 2 dirs and 3 files in my google drive.
I must be missing something, what the right way to get the id of an existing dir.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400669/getting-a-list-of-files-by-folder-on-drive-sdk) question, and it will be helpful if I can get an equivalent java example. I am using the same account's google drive which is owning the app.

Comment: are you sure you are using the latest client lib? that doesnt look anything like Googles Example of how to list files.  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: @DaImTo because he's using the `children` API :) it looks like `files` is for searching content not navigating directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a List of files and iterate.

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential1).build();
String query = "'" + about.getRootFolderId() +"' " + "in parents";
List<File> files = service.files().list().setQ(query).execute().getItems();
return files;
```

This should do.

Comment: Yes that worked. But it appears that it can only list the folders which are created programmatically. Any way to list a folder created via Drive UI ?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code to the [example here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#try-it) you didn't call `execute()` on `list`, I think you're iterating on the request arguments.

Also it says:

> `folderId` To list all files in the root folder, use the alias `root` as the value for `folderId`.

so you can skip getting the `About`.